# git hooks pre-push is not working

Tags: javascript, git, github

Inside git hook folder, I have pre push file inside it i am running "npm run coverage" i.e. command for unit test coverage.

git-hook > pre-push > npm run coverage

but it is not working, can somebody please help me.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions of the pre-push file? The execution bit must be set...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Check if its name is precisely `pre-push` (not `pre-push.sh`, not `pre-push.py`, precisely `pre-push`, with no file extension).
2. Check if it's in `.git/hooks/`. If you have set `core.hooksPath=xxx` in the config, make sure it's under the directory `xxx`.
3. Check if it's executable.
4. Check if the user that runs `pre-push` also has the permission to run `npm run coverage`.

Answer (score 3):

check .git/hooks. If it's empty try to uninstall husky and install again. my sh history

```
 ls .git/hooks
 npm uninstall husky
 npm i husky -D
 ls .git/hooks
```

it helped me

Answer (score -1):

for your short description,I can't  locate the reason. But you can try`husky` or `ghooks`.

`husky` or `ghooks` provide git hooks,such as `precommit`,`prepush`:

```
//husky
{
  "scripts": {
    "precommit": "npm test",
    "prepush": "npm run coverage",
    "...": "..."
  }
}
```